# Is it possible to change or configure the "/openapi" url on which OpenLiberty generates the OpenAPI documentation

Tags: openapi, open-liberty, microprofile

Is it possible to change the url / context-root of the openapi documentation which openliberty generates (microprofile-5.0 and mpConfig-3.0)
By default this is generated on "/openapi" but I was wondering if this can be configured.

I tried to see if it was possible to configure this with mpConfig, with a config file microprofile-config.properties and tried to find more information/documentation/configuration for this this in the server.xml file

Answer (score 0):

There is an open issue https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty/issues/17573 to allow changing this.